# Meaning of momentum after Fourier transforming a propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, propagator

Let the (free, massless) scalar propagator in $4$d be defined in position space as:

$$\left\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \right\rangle \sim \frac{1}{x_{12}^2} \tag{1}$$

with $x_{12}:=x_1 - x_2$ and where factors were suppressed since they are irrelevant to this discussion. The Fourier transform of this propagator is:

$$\left\langle \tilde{\phi}(p_1) \tilde{\phi}(p_2) \right\rangle := \int d^4x_1\ d^4x_2\ e^{-i x_i \cdot p_i} \left\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \right\rangle \sim \frac{1}{p_1^2} \delta^{(4)}(p_1+p_2) \tag{2}$$

Surely the momentum $p_1$ cannot be on-shell, otherwise the propagator just blows up always. Is the $\delta$-function a synonym for saying that it is the momentum $p_1+p_2$ which is on-shell? Why do I have $2$ momenta $p_1$, $p_2$, although it is intuitively clear that there is only one momentum $p$ flowing from $x_1$ to $x_2$?

Comment: The $\delta^4(p_1+p_2)$ means exactly that there is only one momentum in the problem, as it establishes a connection between $p_1$ and $p_2$

Comment: You should also consider the proper integration path giving a backward or a forward propagating in time propagator. This is granted by the $i\epsilon$ prescription.

Comment: @Jon Oh that is a good remark. What would that change in the FT? Is it just a sign?

Comment: @yu-v Thank you for your remark! Can I then say that $p_1 + p_2$ is on-shell?

Comment: @Jxx You have to choose the integration path in such a way that your propagator is defined for $t\rightarrow\infty$ for forward propagation and for $t\rightarrow -\infty$ for backward propagation.

Comment: @Jxx I would say that both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are on-shell. As $p_1+p_2=0$ due to the $\delta^(4)(p_1+p_2)$ it is on-shell in a trivial way

Comment: I would also add that it is not surprising that a free correlator has a pole on-shell, as it means that a particle created on-shell will not decay, which is the case for the free theory. The interpretation of the correlation function is "if I created an excitation of field $A$ at $p_1$ and measured it with field $B$ at $p_2$ what would I get". You can **expect** to have poles at the values of the physical excitations.

Comment: @yu-v That makes sense, thanks a lot for taking the time to develop your comment!