# Are the momenta of the $1/2$-BPS operators in this $2$-point function on-shell?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, supersymmetry, correlation-functions

I recently asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529460/meaning-of-momentum-after-fourier-transforming-a-propagator?noredirect=1#comment1197398_529460) about the Fourier transform of a $2$-point function, and it lead me to another question.

I am looking at $2$-pt functions of $1/2$-BPS operators in $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM in position space, i.e.

$$\left\langle \mathcal{O}(x_1) \mathcal{O}(x_2) \right\rangle\tag{1}$$

with

$$\mathcal{O}(x) := \Phi(x_1)\Phi(x_1) \tag{2}$$

where I suppress the trace over the color indices as well as the harmonic variables since none of that is relevant for this question. $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two arbitrary points in Euclidean space that we keep fixed.

At tree level, $(1)$ looks as follows:

$$\left.\left\langle \mathcal{O}(x_1) \mathcal{O}(x_2) \right\rangle \right|_\text{tree level} \sim \frac{1}{(x_1 - x_2)^4} \tag{3}$$

where the power of $4$ comes from the fact that there are $2$ propagators going from $x_1$ to $x_2$. My question is: if I Fourier transform such an expression, are the momenta on-shell? In short, can I set $p_1^2=0$, $p_2^2=0$? Or in yet other words, can I consider the $1/2$-BPS operators as being external particles?

(Note that the FT is given by:

$$\left.\left\langle \tilde{\mathcal{O}}(p_1) \tilde{\mathcal{O}}(p_2) \right\rangle \right|_\text{tree level} \sim \frac{1}{p_1^4} \delta^{(4)}(p_1 + p_2), \tag{4}$$

similarly to the question that I linked in the first sentence)